# Making a function that can remember a string

Tags: c#

Basically i want to make a function that can be used like this:

```
splitString("stringOfText");
```

This will return a char.

First time the function is run it will return: `s`, 2nd time: `t`, and so on.

It will start at the first character in the string and return the next character the next time the function is run. However. I would like to be able to do this with different strings without having to worry about finishing the first one. This would be used as a part of comparing strings to another, but it's mostly to prove a point. The main issue here is how I can keep track of the different strings at the same time and still have reusable code.

Comment: Anything you've tried?

Comment: Use [`string.GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.getenumerator.aspx) to get an enumerator for the string and then use that to walk through your string.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way is to work with enumerators (let your method return `IEnumerable<char>`). However you solve this, I would definitely chose to return an object that represents your repeatable action, instead of calling the same method with the original string multiple times.

You *could* store the state in a `Dictionary<string, int>`, remembering the last processed index per string. However, the main problem I see is when you're comparing two strings that happen to be *the same*.

Answer (score 1):

Write a class that wrap your string ?
I'm sorry if it doesn't compile it's been a long time since I wrote C#

```
public class StringWrapper {
    private string decomposedString;
    private int index = 0;

    StringWrapper(string decomposeString) {
         decomposedString = decomposeString;
    }

    // Untested code but that's a rough idea, you'd have to test if it fits the length etc...
    public NextLetter() char => decomposedString.at(++index);

}
```

Michael Turczyn answer gives more information.

### Edit:

As poke mentionned in the comment this is basically a `CharEnumerator` that you can get by calling `String.GetEnumerator();`

Comment: What will happen when you go out of bonds? For me it will be better if you keep the index variable in the word length bonds with mod (%) will be the easiest I think

Comment: OutOfRangeException if I remember correctly. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: Congratulations, you just reinvented a [`CharEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.charenumerator.aspx) which you already get by calling `string.GetEnumerator()` since strings are enumerable.

Comment: Why would you be rude... Anyway nice solution, why don't you post an answer then?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to process each character separately, try this:

```
string theString = "stringOfText";
foreach(char c in theString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c); // or whatever you want to do with that char
}
```

A String already implements `IEnumerable<char>`, which means you can iterate over those chars.

Note that this (and any other implementation that just gets "chars") works best on western texts where you don't go crazy over accents. It will fail over asian texts. The reason is that accents may be stored as separate "chars" and that asian characters may need *two* chars. If you want to know more, read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, you would need make a class with such function. Class, due to having fields, can maintain and remember its state, which is what you want. It will contain one (or more) method, you want to use, such as splitting some string.

String to split you can pass in a constructor.

I will leave up to you what class you use (or maybe create own one).

Answer (score 0):

A very basic version could be this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> MyStrings = new Dictionary<string, int>();
public static char NextCharacter(string input)
{
    if (!MyStrings.ContainsKey(input)) MyStrings[input] = 0;
    return input[MyStrings[input]++];
}
```

However, if two of your strings are actually the same, this won't work.
Also, you should add some logic to check for the string length and decide what you want to do if you read beyond the length of your string. This version will throw an OutOfBounds Exception, which may be just fine, depending on your wishes.

If you want to be able to handle equal string, you would have to pass an index to your function, indicating which string you want to handle:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, int> MyIndexes = new Dictionary<int, int>();
public static char NextCharacter(int index, string input)
{
    if (!MyIndexes.ContainsKey(index)) MyIndexes[index] = 0;
    return input[MyIndexes[index]++];
}
```

Note that in that last version, no check is done on whether your string is actually the same as the one you passed the first time, so this would work, but give unexpected results:

```
Console.WriteLine(NextCharacter(1, "ABCDEFG")); // 'A'
Console.WriteLine(NextCharacter(1, "ABCDEFG")); // 'B'
Console.WriteLine(NextCharacter(2, "ABCDEFG")); // 'A'
Console.WriteLine(NextCharacter(2, "ABCDEFG")); // 'B'
Console.WriteLine(NextCharacter(1, "TUVWXYZ")); // this will return 'V'
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem typecly is solved with an yield return statement in c#

```
IEnumerable<char> splitString(string str)
{
    var chars = str.GetEnumerator();
    while (chars.MoveNext())
        yield return chars.Current;
}
```

see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: But why do this? String already implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: is the function not supposed to simply "... return a char." ? "First time the function is run it will return: 's'," not the whole set of chars